# How to format number currency suffix in component antd?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, ant-design-pro

As the title, I have tried many times the code without success, hoping for help from the community

this code format currency prefix!

```
<InputNumber
   defaultValue={1000}
   formatter={value => `$ ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')}
   parser={value => value.replace(/\$\s?|(,*)/g, '')}
/>
```

Comment: Any examples? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)